# How to create null value if value is not the first occurrence based on three columns combination

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a data frame with three columns , wanted to keep only unique values in last column i.e 'CU' based on the the combination three columns.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['Alex','AL',10],['Bob','AB',15],['Clarke','CC',9],['Alex','Ac',11],['Bob','Ay',10],['Clarke','cv',13],['Alex','Ac',11],['Bob','Ay',13],['Clarke','cv',13]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Cat','Cu'],dtype=float)

df
Out[460]: 
     Name Cat    Cu
0    Alex  AL  10.0
1     Bob  AB  15.0
2  Clarke  CC   9.0
3    Alex  Ac  11.0
4     Bob  Ay  10.0
5  Clarke  cv  13.0
6    Alex  Ac  11.0
7     Bob  Ay  13.0
8  Clarke  cv  13.0
```

For the above data frame need to convert CU column value into zero if the combination is not first occurrence. basically trying to identify unique value based on three columns at the same time need to maintain all rows.

```
INPUT:

    df
    Out[460]: 
         Name Cat    Cu
    0    Alex  AL  10.0
    1     Bob  AB  15.0
    2  Clarke  CC   9.0
    3    Alex  Ac  11.0
    4     Bob  Ay  10.0
    5  Clarke  cv  13.0
    6    Alex  Ac  11.0
    7     Bob  Ay  13.0
    8  Clarke  cv  13.0

OUTPUT:

         Name Cat    Cu
    0    Alex  AL  10.0
    1     Bob  AB  15.0
    2  Clarke  CC   9.0
    3    Alex  Ac  11.0
    4     Bob  Ay  10.0
    5  Clarke  cv  13.0
    6    Alex  Ac  0
    7     Bob  Ay  13.0
    8  Clarke  cv  0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-cumcount)

```
df.loc[df.groupby(['Name', 'Cat', 'Cu']).cumcount().gt(0), 'Cu'] = 0
```

---

```
     Name Cat    Cu
0    Alex  AL  10.0
1     Bob  AB  15.0
2  Clarke  CC   9.0
3    Alex  Ac  11.0
4     Bob  Ay  10.0
5  Clarke  cv  13.0
6    Alex  Ac   0.0
7     Bob  Ay  13.0
8  Clarke  cv   0.0
```